# Parsing multiple files in an XML-like format

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have multiple "XML" files in this format:

```
<doc id="123" name="aThing">
BLAH BLAH BLAH
</doc>
<doc id="1234" name="theThing">
BLAH BLAH BLAH
</doc>
<doc id="12345" name="Thing">
BLAH BLAH BLAH
</doc>
```

I've tried using lxml (`ET.fromstring(open('aFile.txt').read()`) and it returns nothing. I tried using BeautifulSoup but it's way too slow. There may be some broken xml like random `</ref>` within each `<doc></doc>`, that's it.

How would I parse that as fast as possible in Python? I would prefer regular expressions because the xml structure doesn't change and it must be fast. I'm not sure how to split the file and also get the id's and names with regex.

Comment: If they aren't fully conformant, validating XML files (and random unmatched </ref>s mean they aren't), don't call them "XML" in the title and tags. Something that isn't XML -- **completely** valid XML -- can't be parsed with an XML parser, which makes the question a completely different one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that's why OP put "XML" in scare quotes, in the body at least.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't automatically fast. There are plenty of questions on SO about slow regexes. Performance is not a reason to prefer regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'<doc id="([^"]*)" name="([^"]*)">(.*?)</doc>', re.DOTALL)

with open('input.txt') as f: xml = f.read()

matches = pat.findall(xml)

print matches
```

Output:

```
[
    ('123', 'aThing', '\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\n'), 
    ('1234', 'theThing', '\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\n'), 
    ('12345', 'Thing', '\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\n')
]
```

The regex/logic may need some tweaking, depending on how ill-formed your input data is.